# How to set Emacs theme?

Tags: emacs, themes, elisp

I am new to emacs and wondering how I would get it to load a theme of my choosing (http://lambda.nirv.net/m/files/color-theme-chocolate-rain.el)

I am on ubuntu, and have no idea what I am doing (yet :P) in regards to Emacs, for the most part.

Answer (score 6):

Download the theme folder or download the '.el' file.
Since you are on ubuntu you'll need to copy the '.el' file in to your theme-load path.
Or create your custom theme-load path as follows

- Make a directory ~/.emacs.d/themes
- Open the '.emacs' file in emacs
- enter the following line at the end of the file
  `(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")`

after copying the '.el' file, add the following line in the .emacs file

`(load-theme 'theme name)`

e.g. `(load-theme 'gotham)`

Save the file and restart emacs.

Comment: As long as the theme you want is one of the standard ones (that you can see with `M-x load-theme <enter> <tab>`), you actually only need the `(load-theme 'themename)` line.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (you probably need to change `color-theme-tty-dark` to `color-theme-chocolate-rain`:

```
;; Enable a color theme
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-tty-dark)
```

Comment: First: `sudo apt-get install emacs-goodies-el` then put the 4 lines above into ~/.emacs.el (creating it if it didn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/.